# VueJS checkbox get Sum and count from data attribute value

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

```
 <tr v-for='(women, index) in womenServices' :key="index">
                        <td class="text-center" style="width: 30px;">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-inline-block">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                                       :id="'chk_wm' + index"
                                       :name="'chk_wm' + index"
                                       :data-price="women.price"
                                       :value="women.id" v-model="womenPackageServices">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" :for="'chk_wm' + index"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            !{women.title}!
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            !{women.price}!
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<input type="text" class="form-control" :v-model="packageServicesSum" placeholder="Total Price" readonly>
```

```
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#addVueServices',
            delimiters: ['!{', '}!'],
            data: {
                womenPackageServices: [],
                packageServicesSum: 0,
            },
            methods: {
                 
            }
            computed: {
                
            },
        })
```

v-model is working absolutely fine, getting id's and updating womenPackagesServices object

But the problem is

**I want to get data attribute value to show SUM of Price and Count of selected Services.**

if there is another easy way to sum price, please help me out i also want to keep womenPackageServices because this array will be passed to database to store selected checkbox ids.

i am not using any components etc and don't want to use.

Comment: i have done this using, jquery 
```
chkService: function (e) {
                    const vue_ = this;
                    vue_.selectedServicesSum = 0;
                    $(".packageServiceChk:checked").each(function () {
                        var i = $(this).data('price')
                        vue_.selectedServicesSum += i;
                    });
                }
```
because I didn't get any response from viewers here but still looking forward if someone can resolve this mytery.

Comment: your code is not complete, what is `womenServices` that you are iterating on ? try to create a shorter more concise example code showing what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolve this issue using jquery in methods because I am not using VUEJS standalone or component-based so it's hard to maybe the long path to get my approach done using VUEJS completely.

so the shortest way to get it done is this.

```
               chkService: function (e) {
                    const vue_ = this;
                    vue_.packages.selectedServicesSum = 0;
                    $(".packageServiceChk:checked").each(function () {
                        var i = $(this).data('price')
                        vue_.packages.selectedServicesSum += i;
                    });
                },
```